# Push notification using GCM with Asp.net server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

If my device is offline or switched off at the time server is sending the push message, then when it is getting online(active) it should receive all pending notifications. It is not receiving the push notification of my app. What might be the reason???? Please help me to solve this issue.

String I am posting from server side(Asp.net server) to GCM server:

String postdata= "collapse_key=score_update"+i+"&time_to_live=2419200&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=‌​"+ message + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString()
                    + "&registration_id=" + deviceToken + "";

Also tried with delay_while_idle=0, but facing same issue. where as "i" is the incremental value that I have appended to collapse key.

Comment: Have you tried different values of time_to_live? Though the value you supplied should work (it's supposed to be the default value that is used if you don't specify that parameter at all), I would try smaller values of time_to_live or even try to send the message without time_to_live. There's a small chance this will make a difference, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Yes but same result. Can you please paste your post data (tested one)

Comment: I tried it myself. The funny thing is I got the message without delay even though the device was idle (locked). I tried both 1 & true (as the GCM guide says) as values for delay_while_idle. In both cases the screen turned on and displayed the notification. Of course this behavior depends on code in the Android application itself, but I thought Google won't send the notification till I unlock the device myself. Here's my post data : registration_id=APA...Cw&collapse_key=something&time_to_live=2419200&delay_while_idle=true&data.payload=Some+Message